# Espérance du nombre de mots connus (vocabulaire passif)

Tags: vocabulaire, linguistique

Existe-t-il des études sur le nombre de mots (moyen) qu'une personne connait (vocabulaire passif) ? C'est un peu vague dit comme ça, mais je ne cherche pas forcément qu'une seule réponse.

Un exemple de réponse qui pourrait m'intéresser serait une étude qui compte le nombre de mots dont les sujets "connaissent" la définition (ça reste un peu vague, mais c'est pour donner l'idée de ce que je cherche).

À l'inverse je ne cherche pas une étude sur l'usage des mots (vocabulaire actif).

Je me demande ça car en lisant des choses à droite à gauche (sans jamais trouver de référence) je vois des chiffres assez petits. Mais en pratique, en jetant un oeil à [Lexique3](https://github.com/chrplr/openlexicon/blob/master/datasets-info/Lexique382/README-Lexique.md#lexique3), j'observe que même des mots peu fréquents font (à mon avis) partie du vocabulaire commun. Ici par exemple avec les mots autour des 60 000èmes plus fréquents :

```
>>> words = lexique.sort_values('freqlemlivres', ascending=False).iloc[60000:60003]
>>> print(words[['ortho', 'freqlemlivres']])

            ortho  freqlemlivres
138961     écrins           3.78
25304   civilisés           3.78
90453     orients           3.78
```

En poussant plus loin, ça devient moins clair (100 000èmes) :

```
            ortho  freqlemlivres
58346  fougeraies           0.61
19040  bénisseuse           0.61
19039  bénisseurs           0.61
19038   bénisseur           0.61
```

Ah, oui, j'ai oublié de préciser, si on compte le nombre de lemmes pour ces 60 000 mots les plus fréquents on trouve 9 441.

**Edit :** On m'a indiqué [cet article](https://www.cairn.info/revue-enfances-et-psy-2010-2-page-30.html?fbclid=IwAR13BRuqFBbT_2aQ-OyCcfw7Tpk1gWJ_aE226So5l1l8m9RjKnccvQa8r08&contenu=article) qui donne un chiffre plus élevé (entre 25 et 40 000 mots), mais encore une fois, ce n'est pas sourcé.

Comment: Comment ça se mesure? Je suis certain qu'il y a des mots que je ne connais pas et dont pourtant je peux trouver la définition en les entendant. Ca m'est arrivé par exemple avec le titre d'un livre de Bernard Werber: "Les thanatonautes".

Comment: Votre question ne porte donc pas sur le comment, mais sur la définition du mot connaitre. Qu'est-ce que ça veut dire comprendre un mot ? Et oui je suis d'accord il y a différents niveaux de compréhension. Je ne suis pas linguiste donc je n'ai aucune idée de la réponse communément admise. Mais pour moi, si on devine correctement la définition d'un mot et qu'on est capable de dire avec certitude qu'il existe alors on connait ce mot. (je mets ça en opposition au mot dont on comprendrait le sens sans qu'il existe pour autant, même si cela remet également en cause la définition même d'existence).

Comment: Comme je le disais, je ne cherche pas un chiffre, mais un chiffre accompagné d'une méthode de mesure. Je ne cherche pas à conclure quoi que ce soit sur la taille du vocabulaire. Donc peu importe la méthode de mesure, peu importe qu'elle soit acceptée tant qu'elle est obtenue de façon rigoureuse ça m'intéresse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Voici un (long) paragraphe, issue de **[cet article](https://www.lextutor.ca/research/nation_waring_97.html)** qui devrait répondre à ta question :

> At present the best conservative rule of thumb that we have is that up to a vocabulary size of **around 20,000 word families**, we should expect that native speakers will add roughly 1000 word families a year to their vocabulary size. That means that a five year old beginning school will have a vocabulary of around 4000 to 5000 word families. A university graduate will have a vocabulary of around 20,000 word families (Goulden, Nation and Read, 1990). These figures are very rough and there is likely to be very large variation between individuals. These figures exclude proper names, compound words, abbreviations, and foreign words. A word family is taken to include a base word, its inflected forms, and a small number of reasonably regular derived forms (Bauer and Nation, 1993).

En ce qui concerne la méthode, il y est dit que :

> For over 100 years there have been published reports of systematic attempts to measure the vocabulary size of native speakers of English. **Unfortunately the measurement of vocabulary size has been bedeviled by serious methodological problems** largely centring around the questions of "What should be counted as a word?", "How can we draw a sample of words from a dictionary to make a vocabulary test?", and "How do we test to see if a word is known or not?". Failure to deal adequately with these questions has resulted in several studies of vocabulary size which give very misleading results. For a discussion of these issues see Nation (1993a), Lorge and Chall (1963), and Thorndike (1924).

En fait, il y a pas mal d'articles (principalement anglo-saxons) qui traitent de ce sujet, et que l'on regroupe sous le terme de ***vocabulary test***. Tu as une synthèse de ce que c'est **[ici](https://www.lextutor.ca/tests/nation_beglar_size_2007.pdf)**. Tous se basent sur à peu près la même méthode : tu as une dizaine de séries de 1000 mots (des plus fréquents au moins fréquents), choisis à partir d'un énorme échantillon de magazines, manuels, etc. Et ensuite ce sont des QCM : 4 définitions sur le même mot et tu dois choisir la bonne.

Récemment **[TestYourVocab](https://www.ecosia.org/search/?q=TestYourVocab&addon=safari&addonversion=4.2.1.51)** a mené une enquête par questionnaire (+2 millions de répondants) en ligne dont les principaux résultats sont exposés [ici](http://testyourvocab.com/blog.php) et sont :

> - *Most adult native test-takers range from 20,000–35,000 words*
> - *Average native test-takers of age 8 already know 10,000 words*
> - *Average native test-takers of age 4 already know 5,000 words*
> - *Adult native test-takers learn almost 1 new word a day until middle age*
> - *Adult test-taker vocabulary growth basically stops at middle age*
> - *The most common vocabulary size for foreign test-takers is 4,500 words*

Pour ce qui est de la langue française, il y a moins d'études. Il y a [cet article](https://www.lextutor.ca/tests/batista_horst_2016.pdf), qui utilise le *Vocabulary Size Test*. Et aussi, [celui-ci](https://www.cerveauetpsycho.fr/sd/psychologie/combien-de-mots-connaissons-nous-3366.php), notamment ce passage :

> Deux études françaises, menées respectivement par les psychologues Stéphane Ehrlich et Agnès Florin, à l'Université de Poitiers, et Moïse Déro à Rennes auprès de plus de 2 500 élèves du ce1 (six à sept ans) au cm2 (neuf à dix ans), s'accordent sur le chiffre de 4 000 mots bien ou moyennement identifiés en ce1, et 9 000 en cm2.